# Canvas is not showing the output on page reload but on hot-reload it does in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

i've been trying working on Canvas inside React but once i'm reloading the page its not showing output but if i'm changing anything in the code with hot-reload it is showing the output,

```js
const [screenWidth, setScreenWidth] = useState(1);
const [screenHeight, setScreenHeight] = useState(2527);
const canvasRef = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
    function windowResizeOnLoad() {
        setScreenWidth((window.innerWidth-2));
    };
    function windowResizeOnResize() {
        setScreenWidth((window.innerWidth - 2));
    };
    windowResizeOnLoad();
    window.addEventListener('resize', windowResizeOnResize);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#D4AF38';
    ctx.moveTo(100, 10);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(100, 90, 1100, 320, 100, 600);
    ctx.stroke(); 
}, [])
```

```html
<canvas width={screenWidth} height={screenHeight} ref={canvasRef}></canvas>
```

Comment: Is there some kind of conditional rendering around the canvas? Is canvasRef defined as the useEffect is initially called? Also, is this plain react or smth. like Next.js? 

Btw. you should be able to remove the windowResizeOnLoad function and just call the windowResizeOnResize function instead. Maybe just rename it to resizeCanvas.

Comment: its a plan react but with Gatsby, so there will be an animation and i'm trying to draw a line where a ball will be moving with the line on scroll but once refreshing the page the line is disapearing and on Hot-Reload its working fine

Comment: wrap Canvas Element in div and give it a height

Comment: its fixed, after using setTimeOut